# MyClass<> myClass = new MyClass<>();

Tags: java

И так. Есть известный класс ArrayList. 
Создание экземпляра класса:
    `ArrayList<SomeClass> myList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();`
Как мне создать свой собственный класс, чтобы его можно было объявлять как показано выше? (Задача состоит в том, чтобы можно было работать с разными классами).

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/generic.php

Comment: То есть, для этого есть специальный раздел обобщения?

Comment: Да, верно. Тут уже есть пример своего класса который использует Дженерики

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный раздел Обобщения.

```
Class X<T> {
//наши методы
}

X<Integer> myX;
```